# retrieve data from database - hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a table called `audits` which has a column 'changes' storing data in the form of hash

I would like to retrieve all entries with the following conditions:

```
- auditable_type = 'Expression'
- action = 'destroy'
- changes = { :EXP_SUBMISSION_FK =>'9999992642'}
```

I first tried the following code which returns me with nothing:

```
@deleted_history = Audit.find(:all, :conditions => ["auditable_type =? AND action = ? AND changes = ?",'Expression', 'destroy' , { :EXP_SUBMISSION_FK =>'9999992642'} ])
```

I then tried the following code which retrieves all entries in the 'audits' table with `auditable_type = 'Expression'` and `action = 'destroy'`.

I then loop through the resultset and discards all entries where EXP_SUBMISSION_FK is not equal to 9999992642. The code below returns me 5 entries/records

```
   @deleted_history = Audit.find(:all, :conditions => ["auditable_type =? AND action = ?",'Expression', 'destroy' ])
    @deleted_history.each do |test|
      if test.changes['EXP_SUBMISSION_FK'] != 9999992642
        @deleted_history = @deleted_history.reject { test }
      end
    end
```

I would like to know where did I go wrong with the first code example and whether there is a way of retrieving all entries with the aforementioned conditions in a much simpler way.

Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i'd do:

```
@deleted_history.select!{|hist| hist.changes['EXP_SUBMISSION_FK'] == '9999992642'}
```

One potential cause of failure is that you're looking for `9999992642` but you state before the value is `'9999992642'`

Comment: Thanks a lot, this solution is working great. I need to remove the '!' after the select command though

Comment: depends: either you do `@deleted_history.select!{}` or `@deleted_history = @deleted_history.select{}`

Answer (score 0):

You just use something like below. I am storing **element_values** as a hash and i am selecting records based on the key/value pair.

```
scope :find_by_field_values, lambda {
  |field_name, field_value| 
  (where("element_values like ?", "%\"#{field_name}\":\"%#{field_value}%"))
}
```

just try this based on your scenario.